# как в css для grid-а плюсануть к fr pixel

Tags: css, css3, scss, css-grid

(два блока)

вот так не работает

```
grid-template-columns: calc(2fr + 8px) 1fr;
grid-template-columns: (calc(2fr + 8px)) 1fr;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переведу для Вас [этот ответ на англоязычной версии SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50389130/using-fraction-fr-in-calc-gives-invalid-property-value):

> Единица `fr` не является стандартной длиной, как проценты или пиксели.
> Онa представляет собой только остаточное пространство.
>
> Следовательно, `fr` нельзя использовать в выражениях `calc()`.
>
> > [**§ 7.2.3. Гибкие длины: единица fr**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#fr-unit)
> >
> > Гибкая длина — это размер с единицей измерения `fr`, который
> > представляет часть остаточного пространства в контейнере сетки.
> >
> > Единицы `fr` не являются длинами, поэтому они не могут быть представлены
> > в выражениях `calc()`.
>
> Но действительно ли вам нужен `calc()`?
>
> `fr` применяется только к оставшемуся пространству, которое остается
> после учета истинной длины, такой как ширина, границы, поля и отступы.

Скорее всего Вам это всё не нужно, просто добавьте отступы в сетке через [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/gap)

Comment: жалко, не мне именно это и нужно было, кстати если юзать gap, то нечего не помешает в px указать значение для grid-template-columns, там длина статична.

Спасибо за перевод и поеснение!